# How can I use const fields of a child class in inherited methods where the parent class has the same const fields?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a base class called Projectile and a child class called SaiBlast.  In my SaiBlast class, I want to use methods inherited from Projectile, but still use const variables belonging to SaiBlast in these inherited methods.

Here's a minimal example.

base class:

```
class Projectile 
{
    protected const float defaultSpeed = 50;

    public void Shoot( float speed = defaultSpeed ) //optional parameter
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

child class:

```
class SaiBlast : Projectile
{
    protected new const float defaultSpeed = 100;
}
```

Now if I say:

```
SaiBlast saiBlast = new SaiBlast();
saiBlast.Shoot();
```

Shoot() should use a value of 100 since that is the default speed for sai blasts.  Right now it uses the default speed for Projectiles in general which is 50. 
I was half expecting this to work because of polymorphism, but I figured I'd run into this problem because the compiler fills in the hard values for constants at compile time.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: are you familiar with using the `Base` Keyword..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am, but I don't see how that would help here. Mind elaborating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Projectile 
{
    protected virtual float DefaultSpeed { get { return 50; } }

    public void Shoot(float? speed = null)
    {
        float actualSpeed = speed ?? DefaultSpeed;
        //Do stuff
    }
}

class SaiBlast : Projectile
{
    protected override float DefaultSpeed { get { return 100; } }
}
```

Comment: Nice! I thought about using a property for the polymorphism, but I couldn't figure out how to completely implement it mostly because I wasn't aware of whatever feature you used for that optional parameter.  I'll have to look that one up :)

Comment: @DennisTraub For polymorphism.  The correct `DefaultSpeed` will always be used, even if doing something like `Projectile p = new SaiBlast(); p.Shoot();`.

Comment: @KacyRaye That's a [nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx).  `float?` is shorthand for `Nullable<float>`.  Then combined it with a [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: Oh I see what you did there.  You turned the parameter into a wrapper making it a reference type rather than a value type and that's why you were able to assign a default value of null to it.  Thanks a lot!